# Redirect all requests to web/app.php in Symfony

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I have my app in xampp/htdocs/zadanie and I want to create .htaccess which will redirect all requests from http://localhost/zadanie/[request] to app.php. By far I was trying with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

( for app_dev to only temporary, just to see what is really going on )

but all requests now are recognized as "/zadanie/[request]", not "/[request]". What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the `xampp/htdocs/zadanie` directory your document root, or move everything in it to the `htdocs` directory.

Comment: How can I do it? I tried to add "DocumentRoot /zadanie/" but than I have only Server error..

Comment: ummm i just realized that You are probably talking about apache files? And I have to do that from .htaccess, without moving all my files anywhere.

Comment: @Mati the document root must be set in your server config, and it has to be a full physical path: `DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/zadanie` or whatever it is.

Comment: so there is no way to do it from .htaccess file?